# chai-as-promised types conflict with chai

Tags: typescript, chai, chai-as-promised

I have unit tests that depend on `chai` and `chai-as-promised` (a library that extends Chai so you can easily test promises)

This assertion:

```
return expect(myPromise).to.eventually.equal(true)
```

gives me compile error

```
error TS2300: Duplicate identifier AssertionError
```

when I have both `@types/chai` and `@types/chai-as-promised` installed.

When I uninstall `@types/chai-as-promised` I get error

```
error TS2339: Property 'eventually' does not exist on type 'Assertion'.
```

So obviously types are necessary

What is going wrong here? Is `chai-as-promised` extending `chai` poorly? Should I create my own types for it?

Comment: Try adding `"exclude": ["@types", "node_modules"]` to your `tsconfig.json`.